# Web Index of Storage Containers Azure

Tags: azure

Is there any way to create an index of a Windows Azure Storage Account Container.
Similar to what you get when you have no index page on a webserver. Just a big list of all the files / folders in the container instead of XML errors.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
```

You'll also need to specify the container level access policy, allowing Full public read access.

Comment: Ah great, any way which that could be hyper-links or something? Still in an XML format that is, i'd prefer something in html.
I mean, I guess I could make a html site which used that as a source and tabulates the contents but if it already does that some way?...

Comment: I suspect not, you'd probably have to do some parsing yourself. Take a look at CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772878.aspx.

Comment: Right Ok. That's for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML readout from this page and enable CORS to do javascript Parsing
http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list